# How do i create a webservice that recieves XML?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asmx

I need to build a web service that accepts XML data.

The XML will send as the below example :

```
<Person>
<LegalName>
  <FirstName>Ralph</FirstName>
  <LastName>Anderson</LastName>
  <PhoneticFirstName>rah-lf</PhoneticFirstName>
</LegalName>
<SSN>122-34-1232</SSN>
<Demographics>
  <Sex>male</Sex>
  <Height>502</Height>
</Demographics>
<DriversLicense>
  <DriversLicenseNumber>1234</DriversLicenseNumber>
  <IssuingState>CA</IssuingState>
</DriversLicense>
```

My understanding is I need to write something like this:

```
public Service () {

    [WebMethod]
    public void CreateRecord(XmlDocument newRecord)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

How I can do that?

Comment: You can receive the XML as string and then parse it to XML.

Comment: Ok,How i can do that ??

Comment: You mentioned you *"need to build a web service"* - do you specifically want to build `asmx` web service or any web service will do? Like Web API or MVC or WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to understand how it works and find a nice artical here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534080.aspx

Comment: Please don't judge him to downvote him hes trying to learn something.